# Passing Ruby SQL View parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a lot of data that I need to query out of a database. Heroku is timing out when I do the following, because of the 30 second limit:

```
account.records.all.each do |record|
   record.contacts.all.each do |contact|
     contact.address.all.each do |address|
             ..write to file etc
     end
   end
end
```

I've read that an SQL View will help with performance rather than querying every record in a .each(), however I need to do a where clause on this set of data. Currently, if I use the 'ExportAllRecord' view like so: ExportAllRecords.where("account_id = 3"), it executes the following:

```
ExportAllRecord Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "export_all_records".* FROM "export_all_records" WHERE (account_id = 3)
```

whereas, I actually need it to add the 'where clause' to the view.

How can I parameterise the SQL View?

I'm using ActiveRecord.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` doesn't care where it queries from a normal database table or a database view.

Assuming your database view is named `export_all_records`, then just create a new model:

```
# in app/model/export_all_record.rb
class ExportAllRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { readonly }
end
```

Use this model like a normal `ActiveRecord` model:

```
id = 3 # or perhaps params[:id]
ExportAllRecord.find_by(account_id: id)
#=> returns all records from the view with the given id
```

You can add more conditions if you need to:

```
ExportAllRecord.
  where(account_id: id).
  where(column1: true, column2: 'foobar')
  order(:column3)
```

Comment: I understand that, but I don't want the entire view to be executed, which then does a WHERE on the result. The ExportAllRecord view has a LOT of information returned.

Comment: I am not sure if we use the same definition of `view` and what you mean by *entire view to be executed*. I think we are talking about [materialized views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) in the database that in the context of `SELECT` queries basically acts like common tables. Just use the Rails query methods to scope the result. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I'm performing a Where clause on the database view. Will a select on the view be executed, followed by a where account = 3 on the results? There is a lot of data in this database, and if we're not performing a where account_id = ? inside the view, I'm concerned it will take a very long time to execute.

Comment: Nope, this is just one query to the database and only matching record will be returned.